# Scanning a string with spaces from a file while also scanning numbers before and after it in the same line

Tags: c, scanf

I'm actually new learner so I got a bug while learining , I'm actually trying to `fscanf` from file then display it on the screen everything works fine until i add name of a book with space in the file. It displays `book.id` fine but it only displays the first name of  the book and the integer after that changes to 0.

**Sample output:**

[image]

**My function:**

```
void display_unsorted(FILE *fptr){
    int x;
    int lines_num=how_many_lines_in_file(fptr);

    fptr=fopen("books.dat","r");
    if(fptr==NULL){
    printf("this file is not open");}

    for(i=0;i<lines_num;i++){
    fscanf(fptr,"%d\t%s\t%d\n",&books[i].id,books[i].name,&books[i].quantity);
    }
    for(x=0;x<lines_num;x++){
    printf("%d\t%s\t%d\n",books[x].id,books[x].name,books[x].quantity);
    }

    fclose(fptr);    
}
```

Comment: please do not post images.  Rather, select/copy the text and paste into your question as text

Comment: regarding: `if(fptr==NULL){
    printf("this file is not open");}`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function, then should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling: `perror( "this file is not open" );`  2) this is a unrecoverable error so the next statement should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )`  NOT trying to read from the file

Comment: Please give the file format. How exactly are the different fields delimited? If spaces are allowed in the book name then the delimiter cannot be space.

Comment: Post definition of `books[]` and `books[i].name`.

Comment: Try reading with `"%d %14[^\t\n]%d\n"`

Comment: This: `"%d\t%s\t%d\n"` indicates hints that the field separator is a <tab> in the input file.  Is this true?

Comment: @user3629249 yes and thanks for the code below it works <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf` will stop reading when it finds a blank space, you can override this behavior by using:

```
fscanf(fptr,"%d %99[^0-9] %d\n", &books[i].id, books[i].name, &books[i].quantity);
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

Translating, will read a string with 99 characters at most, will stop reading when it finds any digit, i.e. characters from 0 to 9.

I removed the `\t`, it's unnecessary, even if the file has them, a blank space will suffice.

Note that this is for a `books[i].name` container with the maximum size of 100 chars, that's 99 chars plus the null terminator, this must be adapted to the size of the container which is not revealed in your code.

Also note this won't work as expected if the string has digits in it.

Comment: @omaranas, I'm glad I could help, don't forget to [accept one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the field delimiter in the input file is a `<tab>`, which the OP is not clear about, except for the format string in the call to `fscanf()` then

```
fscanf(fptr,"%d\t%s\t%d\n",&books[i].id,books[i].name,&books[i].quantity);
```

could be changed to:

```
fscanf( fptr,"%d %[^\t] %d",
             &books[i].id,
              books[i].name,
             &books[i].quantity );
```

where the 'set' format specifier: `%[^\t]` would continue to input characters until a `<tab>` is encountered.  The `<tab>` would be left in the input stream, however, the following space would consume that `white space`, (as would the `%d`), however the space is much more readable.

Comment: "because the spaces in the format string will absorb/discard the white space" --> tabs (new line, CR, VT, etc.)  in the format string do the same thing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica,  The OPs original format string will not allow the call to `fscanf()` to return until the first non-white space is encountered (most likely at the beginning of the next line of data.  This is not a good thing, You will notice that the format string I suggested does not contain any trailing white space characters.

Comment: Yes, saw that - yet the suggested format changed 2 things (\t to space and dropped last whitespace) and answer appears to discount tab doing the same as spaces.   With `stdin`, I'd agree about "This is not a good thing".  With a file input, the white-space at the end of a format makes scant difference - the next input already exist.  IAC, with _line_ input, best to read a line as with  `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned `strchr` could be used to find the first space and `strrchr` to find the last space. The difference between those pointers is the characters in the name.
`sscanf` can be used to parse the leading and trailing integers.
`strncpy` can be used to copy the name from the interior of the line.
This program only processes one line. Wrapping this in `while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fptr))` will process each line from the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char line[200] = "123 firstname lastname 456\n";
    char name[120] = "";
    char *first = line;
    char *last = line;
    int leading = 0;
    int trailing = 0;
    int valid = 1;
    int span = 0;
    int result = 0;

    if ( ( first = strchr ( line, ' '))) {
        if ( ( last = strrchr ( line, ' ')) && last > first) {
            result = sscanf ( line, "%d", &leading);
            result += sscanf ( last, "%d", &trailing);
            if ( 2 != result) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "two numbers needed\n");
                valid = 0;
            }
            while ( ' ' == *first) {
                ++first;//skip leading space
            }
            while ( ' ' == *last) {
                --last;//skip trailing space
            }
            span = 1 + last - first;//characters in name
            if ( span < sizeof name) {
                strncpy ( name, first, span);
                name[span] = 0;
            }
            else {
                fprintf ( stderr, "name is too long\n");
                valid = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "two spaces needed\n");
            valid = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf ( stderr, "spaces needed\n");
        valid = 0;
    }

    if ( valid) {
        printf ( "name %s\n", name);
        printf ( "leading number %d\n", leading);
        printf ( "trailing number %d\n", trailing);
    }

    return 0;
}
```